# Splitting a DynamoDB result into a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to split this array in Python that I pulled down from a DynamoDB table into separate chunks so that I can then calculate the Averages of each AssetID, storing the AssetID and the Rating into separate parts of the Array.

```
[{'ID': Decimal('0'), 'AssetID': Decimal('0'), 'Rating': Decimal('3')}, {'ID': Decimal('1'), 'AssetID': Decimal('0'), 'Rating': Decimal('5')}]
```

So for example, I would like the array to look like the following:

```
AssetIDArray[AssetID][Rating]
```

So hence if I were to print the following, I would get 5.

```
AssetIDArray[0][1]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dict instead of a list as AssetIDs:

```
from decimal import Decimal

items = [{'ID': Decimal('0'), 'AssetID': Decimal('0'), 'Rating': Decimal('3')},
         {'ID': Decimal('1'), 'AssetID': Decimal('0'), 'Rating': Decimal('5')}]

parsed_item_list = {}

for item in items:
    assetId = int(item.get('AssetID'))
    rating = int(item.get('Rating'))
    if assetId not in parsed_item_list:
        parsed_item_list[assetId] = []
    parsed_item_list[assetId].append(rating)

print(parsed_item_list.get(0)[0]) # 3
print(parsed_item_list.get(0)[1]) # 5
```